# Django permission_classes for access to route is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to change the permissions to specific routes. Some routes I want to be open, other routes I want the user to be authenticated. My code is the following:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet

class UserViewSet(GenericViewSet):
      queryset = User.objects.all()
      serializer_class = UserSerializer
      permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
      renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]


    @action(url_path="an/api/path", detail=False, methods=["post"], renderer_classes=[JSONRenderer])
    @api_view(['GET'])
    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
    def get_stuff(self, request):
        #Will get stuff
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
 File "/code/api/views/UserViewSet.py", line 16, in <module>
api_1     |     class UserViewSet(GenericViewSet):
api_1     |   File "/code/api/views/UserViewSet.py", line 33, in UserViewSet
api_1     |     @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
api_1     | TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

In my settings.py, I have:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer",
    )
```

Any idea why it keeps throwing list' object is not callable function?

Comment: try `@permission_classes(IsAuthenticated)` if works

Comment: @AmitNanaware no @permission_classes(IsAuthenticated) threw the same error

Comment: @DevinDixon what is your DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES looks like in settings.py?

Comment: @chamoda I added to the question above

Comment: Are you sure your are not redefining `permission_classes` anywhere in this file before you use it as a decorator? Maybe try a `print(permission_classes)` before and check on the console if it's really the expected function...

Comment: @BernhardVallant would this do it?  permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

Comment: Yes this redefines `permission_classes` to this list... I also just didnt notice that it is even in the same class :/

Answer (score 2):

Remove `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]`. It overrides the decorator.

```
class UserViewSet(GenericViewSet):
      queryset = User.objects.all()
      serializer_class = UserSerializer
      renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]


    @action(url_path="an/api/path", detail=False, methods=["post"], renderer_classes=[JSONRenderer])
    @api_view(['GET'])
    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
    def get_stuff(self, request):
        #Will get stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that without aliasing the name of the decorator, the class will think you're trying to use the internal property "permission_classes".

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes as view_permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet

class UserViewSet(GenericViewSet):
      queryset = User.objects.all()
      serializer_class = UserSerializer
      permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
      renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer]


    @action(url_path="an/api/path", detail=False, methods=["post"], renderer_classes=[JSONRenderer])
    @api_view(['GET'])
    @view_permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
    def get_stuff(self, request):
        #Will get stuff
```